# Is it true that a male's intelligence is solely affected by genes inherited from the mother?

Tags: intelligence

Refer to an Independent article ( circa 1996), ["Brainy sons owe intelligence to their mothers"](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/brainy-sons-owe-intelligence-to-their-mothers-1339099.html)

> Intelligent men owe their brains to their mothers, according to
>   research published today in The Lancet.
>
> Growing evidence shows that several genes which determine intelligence
>   appear to be located on the X chromosome, the one men inherit from
>   their mothers .Any mutation on the X chromosome has more effect on a
>   man than a woman because a woman inherits X chromosomes from both her
>   parents, which tends to dilute the gene's impact.
>
> But a man only has one X chromosome inherited from his mother, which
>   is paired with the much smaller Y chromosomes from his father.
>   Therefore, an intelligence-enhancing X gene has more of a chance of
>   becoming the predominate gene, determining the man's basic
>   intelligence, looks and character.

[WSJ carried similar story](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB835919711841023500).

> Sorry, Dad. You may be responsible for your son's big nose, but all
>   the credit for the kid's genius goes to Mom.
>
> ....
>
> **Boys inherit their intelligence from their mothers**, according to
>   Gillian Turner, an Australian geneticist. She cites growing evidence
>   that several genes for intelligence are located on the X chromosome,
>   which men inherit only from their mothers (along with a tiny Y from
>   their fathers). Women, in contrast, receive an X chromosome from each
>   parent so they can theoretically inherit their father's intelligence.

Is this a claim accepted by the scientific community?

Comment: I don't see "solely" anywhere in that excerpt.

Comment: @NateEldredge, question updated with more quotes

Comment: I guess you're focusing on the oversimplified headlines, but the bodies of the articles seem to make clear that the only real claim is that genes inherited from the mother are *among* those which affect intelligence.

Comment: A very similar question was already asked [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26758/is-approximately-80-of-a-childs-intelligence-acquired-from-the-mother?rq=1).

Comment: @NateEldredge, if you like, I've edited the title. But the content stays essentially the same

Comment: @NateEldredge, the quoted question is different from mine. Mine concentrate soley on male's IQ.

Comment: Also, have you seen http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23142/do-the-mothers-genes-almost-exclusively-determine-the-sons-intelligence?rq=1 ?

Comment: No, I didn't see it. But when I saw it, the question does address the same topic as mine does... only that it is closed for "unclear". I think the closure is unwarranted, and that this ( or that) question deserves proper reply, instead of just comments that don't quite help to clarify the issues.

Comment: You can start a meta thread to discuss why the question should be reopened.

Comment: Why my question downvoted?

Comment: @NateEldredge, [meta question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3683/214) filed